# Not able to fetch log files from shell using python

Tags: python, shell, logging, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess module with Popen to fetch log from a specified URL, However, I am not able to fetch the log and the program returns me a blank.

I have been using the below mentioned code:

```
import subprocess
url = r'C:\project\dummy\pro'
mycmd = ['svn', 'log', url]

log = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, shell=True,
                            stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

result = log.wait()
out1, err = log.communicate()
print out1
```

I need the output string to use as next part of the program. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove `log.wait()`. Add `result = log.returncode` *after* `.communicate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without `shell=True`:

```
log = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, 
                       stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: It worked the way i wanted, except, a blank screen for \bin\svn.exe pops up and doesn;t close by itslef and once i close it, rest of the program runs fine.